# Is it possible to upload to App Store using Xcode 9 GM?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios11, xcode9

I just prepared an app which is compatible with iOS 11. When I export through Xcode 9 GM I'm not getting any issue. same thing I'm exporting through Xcode 8.3.3 getting alignment issue on one page.

Can we upload an application through Xcode 9 GM or shall we need to wait until an official update for Xcode 9 in Mac Appstore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see the email that Apple sent you on September 12th?

Comment: Ya iOS 11 release on sep 19.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes developer can upload binary through GM(Golden Master) Xcode build actually this is a pre
>   release of final Xcode build it can be used to build & submit to App Store. In beta release developer can only use
>   to develop app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.