# How to submit apps for iOS 11 before its official release ?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

What version of XCode should I use to submit an iOS app for iOS 11 devices ?

Should a XCode 9 beta version work ?

Should only a 'GM' version work ? (what does GM mean by the way ?)

Should I wait for a further version ?

Thanks

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271158/is-it-possible-to-upload-to-app-store-using-xcode-9-gm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use GM Seed version to release your app before iOS11 release.

Don't use any beta to publish your apps, even frameworks if in use of some beta.

GM stands for Gold Master. It's the finalized firmware before public release.